# Ideal generated by $yw-x^2$ and $z^2w-2xyz+y^3$ is not radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

> How to prove that ideal generated by $yw-x^2$ and $z^2w-2xyz+y^3$ is not radical?

This is one interpretation of the twisted cubic curve which is said to be not a radical ideal.

Comment: Try $(y^2-xz)^2$.

Comment: Hi, may I know, how do you generate the counter example?

Comment: Your twisted cubic is the $2\times 2$-minors of $\begin{pmatrix} w & x & y \\ x & y & z\end{pmatrix}.$ 

Think of $z^2w-2xyz+y^3$ as $-\det{\begin{pmatrix} w & x & y \\ x & y & z\\ y&z&0 \end{pmatrix}}$

Now, see the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic)-example which is for $\begin{pmatrix} X & Y & Z \\ Y & Z & W\end{pmatrix}$.